# Pattern in a specific range in the prime twin numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

**I found this pattern, does it have any mathematical significance or something else?**

From twin (5,7) to twin (101,103) there is a common pattern in that area.

(P+1)^2 - 6=A

A/6=E

E: Prime number

**the pattern**

6^2 - 6=30

30/6=5 prime

---

12^2 - 6=138

138/6=23 Prime

---

18^2 -6=318

318/6=53 prime

---

30^2 - 6=894

894/6=149 Prime

---

42^2 - 6=1758

1758/6=293 prime

---

60^2 -6=3594

3594/6=599

---

72^2 -6=5178

5178/6=863 Prime

---

102^2 -6=10398

10398/6=1733 Prime

Comment: The last one is a typo, right ? It should be $102^2-1$. So, if $p$ is the smaller prime of the form $6k-1$, we have $6k^2-1$. The next $3$ casea are composite, but primes appear also later. Do you ask whether infinite many primes of this kind exist ?

Comment: If the Schinzel hypothesis is true, infinite many such primes exist , that so many small prime cases exist has the reason that $2$ and $3$ cannot be prime factors $5$ as a prime factor appears only once , namely for the twin $5/7$. Nevertheless, many examples before a composite appears !

Comment: @Peter Yes, it was a typo and it has been corrected, the syntax certainly doesn't check all the twins in a row later, nor does trying find a lot of examples with the code. Certainly, the question of this formula infinitely is a very difficult question. My question about Ali is it possible for that style of any significance?

Comment: It is a nice observation, but I do not think that it has any deeper significance.

Comment: Do you mean if the Schinzel hypothesis becomes true, we can bet on the formula you mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Peter I find a lot of patterns in the primes, and sometimes I find strange long patterns, so I ask if they might become important, I do it as a hobby

Comment: This conjecture would make sure that infinite many such cases exist giving a prime. But of course, the frequency will decrease with larger cases.

Comment: It is true that there may be a decrease in the sequence. The most important thing is that the formula continues to achieve huge examples, even if they become few.

Maybe ask in the Python section for someone to help me with more tests in a quick time.

Answer (score 1):

All twin prime pairs except $(4,6)$ have the form $(6k-1, 6k+1)$.  If you pick the lower one ($P=6k-1$), then $(P+1)^2 = (6k)^2$ will obviously be a multiple of 6, and thus so will $A=(P+1)^2-6$.

It seems that you're asking if $E = \frac{A}{6}$ is “usually” prime.  This can be tested with a simple Python program:

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    limit = int(math.sqrt(n) + 2)
    for divisor in range(2, limit):
        if n % divisor == 0:
            return False
    return True

def primes(limit):
    '''
    Return a list of all prime numbers 2 <= n < limit.
    '''
    result = []
    potential = range(2, limit)
    while potential:
        next_prime = potential[0]
        result.append(next_prime)
        potential = [n for n in potential if n % next_prime]
    return result

LIMIT = 1000
PRIME_LIST = primes(LIMIT)
TWIN_PRIMES = [
    pair for pair in (
        (PRIME_LIST[i], PRIME_LIST[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(PRIME_LIST)-1)
    ) if pair[1] - pair[0] == 2
]

examples = []
counterexamples = []
for (p, _) in TWIN_PRIMES:
    a = (p + 1) ** 2 - 6
    e = a // 6
    if is_prime(e):
        examples.append(p)
    else:
        counterexamples.append(p)

print('examples = ', examples)
print('counterexamples = ', counterexamples)
```

I get the output:

- examples =  [3, 5, 11, 17, 29, 41, 59, 71, 101, 179, 191, 227, 269, 311, 347, 419, 461, 521, 599, 857]
- counterexamples =  [107, 137, 149, 197, 239, 281, 431, 569, 617, 641, 659, 809, 821, 827, 881]

Comment: Know that the formula does not check for all possible examples, like Mersenne does not check for all numbers, but it appears even if the difference between the numbers increases

Comment: FWIW, I calculated a longer `example` list: [5, 11, 17, 29, 41, 59, 71, 101, 179, 191, 227, 269, 311, 347, 419, 461, 521, 599, 857, 1061, 1319, 1427, 1451, 1481, 1487, 1697, 1721, 1787, 1871, 1877, 1931, 2087, 2111, 2129, 2237, 2309]

Comment: Yes, l am sorry

Comment: Thank you for making the code, in general would a pattern like this matter?

Comment: I have a question, I make patterns but I can't be sure with more examples because I don't know the code, what do I learn specifically to make programs like these ideas